# Segue to home screen if Anonymous user exists on the database

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using **PFAnonymousUtils** and **PFUser.enableAutomaticUser**. I want to check if the user exist is the database, if so i want to pivot to DiscoverViewController.

The problem is that even if there is no user the app keeps forwarding to DiscoverVc...

```
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if currentUser != nil {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // instantiate your desired ViewController
        let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiscoverVc")

        // Because self.window is an optional you should check it's value first and assign your rootViewController
        if self.window != nil {
            self.window!.rootViewController = rootController
        }

    } else {

        let installation = (PFInstallation.currentInstallation())
        installation["User"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        installation.saveInBackground()

        PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil || user == nil {

                print("Anonymous user failed")

            } else {

                print("Anonymous user logged in.")
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From parse documentation:

PFUser.enableAutomaticUser

> After calling this method, currentUser will always have a value. The
>   user will only be created on the server once the user has been saved,
>   or once an object with a relation to that user or an ACL that refers
>   to the user has been saved.

To check if the user is an Anonymous user use:

```
PFAnonymousUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser())
```

> Return Value YES if the user is anonymous. NO if the user is not the
>   current user or is not anonymous.